# 'is_authenticated' still always returns false in template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

This is following on from my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569728/how-do-i-allow-my-django-admin-console-url-to-take-priority), as it will likely require a different answer.

The code in my template is always returning false:

```
   {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
      <p>I'm logged in</p>
   {% else %}
      <p>I am anonymous</p>
   {% endif %}
```

I understand from the docs that I need to include "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth" within `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in settings.py so I have done so as follows:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth", #Added
)
```

As for my views.py, I am using the `render_to_response()` but feel this may be causing the issue. I also need to pass a user from the database within the context, but have added the third parameter `context_instance=RequestContext(request)`

```
def public_profile(request, username_in_url):
    user = User.objects.get(username = username_in_url)
    context = {
        'user': user,       
    }

    return render_to_response('public_profile.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Why does `request.user.is_authenticated` still return false even though a user is logged in? Using the same method within views.py works **correctly** e.g.

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render_to_response('public_profile.html', context)
    else:
        return render_to_response('public_profile_anon.html', context)
```

Comment: Does it work if you use user.is_authenticated in your template instead?

Comment: If I change it to user.is_authenticated then it has the opposite effect! it always returns **true**!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth) for `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` says that this context processor defines two variables: `user` and `perms`. And `user` is

> An `auth.User` instance representing the currently logged-in user (or an `AnonymousUser` instance, if the client isn’t logged in).

So although in your Python code you would access `request.user` to perform your check, in the template it is `user`.

The problem with your specific case is that you also pass a dictionary that defines `user` on the basis of `username_in_url`. This clashes with the variable defined by `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth`.

So:

1. Change the dictionary (which you named `context`) so that `user` has a different name. (And change references to it in your template.)
2. Change your template to check `{% if user.is_authenticated %}`.